# How to make an id auto_increment from where it last left off after a record delete?

Tags: mysql

This isn't that big of a deal but I was wondering if it can be done. Right now when I insert a new record, the id field which is auto_increment and set as primary key increases it's value by one:

```
id | first_name | last_name
------------------------------
1  | John       | Smith
2  | Jane       | Doe
```

But if I delete record 2, the next one I insert is going to have an id of 3. Is there any way to make it have an id of 2 automatically (without having to manually insert it)?

Comment: it can be done, but not without performance cost. I wouldn't be bothered.

Comment: @Sander - What performance cost is there in my answer? If this was Wikipedia I would write [Citation needed] on your comment.

Comment: calculating MAX(id) on each delete might get expensive if your table gets big, and you need a transaction around it too (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auto_increment` counter *(at least, with InnoDB)* is kept in the table meta-data, and is independant of the data that's in the table : it is incremented when some data is inserted, and that is all.

So, no, it's not possible to have your `auto_increment` column get the biggest value + 1 -- or, at least, not at insert-time.

I suppose a solution could be to `alter` the table, to force the `auto_increment` counter to a new value, though. Not sure you can set it to a lower value than it's current one, though *(which is precisely what you're trying to do)*.

For more informations, see this paragraph on [the manual page of `alter table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) *(quoting, emphasis mine)* :

> To change the value of the
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT`  counter to be used
>   for new rows, do this:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
> ```
>
> **You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that
>   have already been used**. 
> For
>   MyISAM, if the value is less than or
>   equal to the maximum value currently
>   in the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, the
>   value is reset to the current maximum
>   plus one. 
> For InnoDB, if the value
>   is less than the current maximum value
>   in the column, no error occurs and the
>   current sequence value is not changed.

So, according to the manual :

- You can change the value of `auto_increment`
- You can set it to the maximum value (plus one ? ) of the column in the table.

  - Be careful about the way you're doing this, though, as trying to use a *too-low* value, with InnoDb, will result in no change.

Still, note that using `alter table` should probably not be done *too often*...

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id = 4;
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = MAX(id) + 1;
```

Comment: I think you need a transaction around that as well, to prevent insert from happening in between `DELETE` and `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: This causes an error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE names AUTO_INCREMENT = MAX(id) + 1' at line 2